# Gravity and resistance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, density, fluid-statics

I don't really understand gravity and don't really believe in it to be honest. But people a lot smarter than me do so I can live with that.
My questions if someone could be so kind to answer ...

1. Why doesn't gravity effect the helium in a balloon?
2. How can NASA have zero gravity rooms?
3. Does a pound of feathers and a pound of bricks have the same mass?
4. Does the density of an object affect the effect of gravity?

Comment: Hi Richard, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I've put this on hold because we prefer people to ask one question per post.

Comment: These questions show no indication of prior research. What did you find when reading Wikipedia?

Comment: @Chappo He could be a troll, but I've answered him in case he is instead a science skeptical and with a small hope he'll try to understand my answer.

Comment: Thank you for those who answered and apologies for the spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

> 1.Why doesn't gravity effect helium in a balloon

It does. What happens to it is the same that happens to an inflated ball pushed into a swimming pool: the weight of the displaced water is larger than the weight of the ball, so it pushes it up stronger than gravity pulls the ball down.

> 2.how can NASA have zero gravity rooms

It doesn't. It does most of its training in swimming pools (see above) and some practice/experiments in flights/stations that move as if in free fall - a situation where you *feel* weightless, but aren't.

> 3.does a pound of feathers and a pound of bricks have the same mass

Yes.

> 4. Does the density of am object effect the affect of gravity

Directly, no. But, again think of a swimming pool, other effects do depend on density.

Comment: Thank you,  I am not a troll i just struggle with this side of science. The thoight that there are more stars in the sky then grains of sand blows my mind. I have never been able to get my head round mass and density . I know they are two very basic aspects but I still struggle.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the answer . I struggle with this side of science. Things that I find hard to believe in I struggle to understand. But cheers

Comment: @Richard, you are at the right place for asking and skepticism is a healthy attitude. Above all, it's really great when people try to understand some science they are suspicious about, instead of simply dismissing it. Lastly, please take no offense at that comment of mine, I simply said you "could be" a troll, because those do show up every now and then. Keep bringing your questions and someone will probably be happy to answer them. All the best.